# Qt Kits: two gcc versions; compiles but does not find libgomp.so.1, libstdc++.so.6,

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

I want build an application on a CENTOS7 computer which requires a higher `gcc` version as provided by default.

Since I do not have sudo rights, I build all dependencies (such as gcc) in my home directory.

Now I was trying to build my application using QT-Creator. 
I tried to create a new Qt-Kit using:

- *QT-Creator/Tools/Options/Compilers*: I have added two new compilers, a C++ (I set the `compiler path` to my local g++ binary) and a C (I set the `compiler path` to my local gcc binary)
- *QT-Creator/Tools/Options/Kits*: I have cloned the existing (Auto-detected) kit and changed the Compiler values to the 2 new compilers
- I selected the new Kit in my program, switched to the Release build and clicked on `build` (the hammer on the bottom left)

The build finishes without problems.

However, if I want to run the application (by clicking on the green triangle) the `Application output` list the following errors:

> /lib64/libgomp.so.1 version `GOMP_5.0` not found
>
> /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26` not found
>
> /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` not found
>
> /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` not found

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I just tried to build one of the Qt Examples and it worked with both Kits, the auto-detected and the manually created one. Maybe the error is not related to the Kits? It can't be an error in the source code since it compiles well and I run the same code on Windows and Ubuntu without problems.

Comment: The code which is running without problems run by *sudo command* or without *sudo*? And if you can share a piece of code using those libraries,we can also try .

Comment: Everything is started from the Qt-Creator, (no sudo). I'm trying to figure out which part of the code leads to the problem, although I think it is probably not related to the code but to the Qt-Creator settings or a missing dependency...